# Check if there are prior entries of a Customer_Id in a table and return it's Status

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a CustomerTable with CustomerID's listed in a table. I want to create a new column called STATUS that checks if he is a new customer with previous rows present in the table and returns `TRUE` for a new customer `FALSE` if there exists already a record in the table. Is there a way it can be done using `dplyr`. Also, I don't want to `sort` the table by CUSTOMER_ID's

```
## Input would be just the CUSTOMER_ID's from the below table and the Output STATUS is appended to it.

   CUSTOMER_ID STATUS
1:         101  FALSE
2:         102  FALSE
3:         103  FALSE
4:         101   TRUE
5:         104  FALSE
6:         105  FALSE
7:         106  FALSE
8:         103   TRUE
9:         104   TRUE
```

Comment: Looks like you need `df1[, STATUS := duplicated(CUSTOMER_ID)]`

Comment: damn!! That's simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just took the tip from the comment and posting the answer since I can't delete the question.

```
CustomerData %>% mutate(STATUS = duplicated(CUSTOMER_ID))

  CUSTOMER_ID STATUS
1         101  FALSE
2         102  FALSE
3         103  FALSE
4         101   TRUE
5         104  FALSE
6         105  FALSE
7         106  FALSE
8         103   TRUE
9         104   TRUE
```